# Chartjs tooltip pointstyle border radius

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I want to change borderRadius of tooltip pointStyle in chart.js but I'm having trouble.
I was able to make line pointStyle wider but cannot apply any border radius to it.

Here is my configuration and screenshot:
[image]

```
 const options = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                usePointStyle: true,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(17, 24, 39, 1)',
                bodyColor: 'rgba(209, 213, 219, 1)',
                borderWidth: 4,
                callbacks: {
                    labelPointStyle: function () {
                        return {
                            pointStyle: 'line' as PointStyle,
                            rotation: 90,
                        };
                    },
                    labelColor: function () {
                        return {
                            borderColor: 'rgba(245, 101, 245, 1)',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(192, 111, 244, 0.25)',
                        };
                    },
                    title: function () {
                        return '';
                    },
                    label: function (tooltipItems: TooltipItem<'radar'>) {
                        return `${tooltipItems.label} ${tooltipItems.formattedValue}%`;
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    };

    return (
        <>
            <canvas
                ref={chartContainer}
                className='hidden'
            />
            {chartData && (
                <Radar
                    data={chartData}
                    options={options}
                />
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```